# why vulnerable time in pure aloha is not tp

Tags: computer-networks, access-control

I understand that vulnerable time in CSMA cd is Tp (Propagation time). This is because collision can occur in Tp duration since one bit has to travel to the end.

My question is- Why that is not true in the case of Aloha ?. Why we do not have the same vulnerable time in Aloha?

That question has already been asked but no responses.- [Vulnerable Time in ALOHA](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148757/vulnerable-time-in-aloha)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the vulnerable time in pure aloha twice the frame time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82542/why-is-the-vulnerable-time-in-pure-aloha-twice-the-frame-time)

Comment: @Zac67 No. I have already read that answer. My question is in comparison with CSMA CD. Why both of these are behaving so differently ?

Comment: i will highly appreciate if anyone can help in this.