# Why is vulnerable time equal to 2*Tp where Tp is Transmision time? (pure-ALOHA)

Tags: computer-networks, tcp

In pure aloha the if one frame is been transmitted and another is send during the transmission then the whole frames get destroyed.
Vulnerable time is the time period where there is the chance for collision.
But why is it set to 2*Tp where
Tp: Transmission time

I watch some you-tube it said It is 2*Tp because we have to take in consideration of the current frame and the previous frames. Why do we have to consider the previous frames?

Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lEvqxp9ODQ&ab_channel=KNOWLEDGEGATE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the vulnerable time in pure aloha twice the frame time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/82542/why-is-the-vulnerable-time-in-pure-aloha-twice-the-frame-time)